# Average from two different table using group by

Tags: group-by, inner-join

I have a table Called DEPARTMENTS with Columns:
DepartmentID
DepartmentName

Another table Called EMPLOYEE with Columns:
EmployeeID
DepartmentID
EmployeeName
Salary

I need a JOIN query with possibly Group By to display DepartmentName and AVERAGE Salary

Basically the Output should display: 
DepartmentX  40000
DepartmentY  15000
DepartmmentZ 35000

Comment: Hi Akram, Can you post what you have tried so far? It will help us, help you debug your issue. Also, what database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `AVG()` aggregate function with `JOIN` between two tables like

```
SELECT d.DepartmentName,
AVG(e.Salary) as average_salary
FROM Employee e 
JOIN DEPARTMENTS d ON e.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID 
GROUP BY e.DepartmentID;
```

(OR) get the average first and then perform a `JOIN` like

```
SELECT d.DepartmentName,
xx.average_salary
FROM DEPARTMENTS d 
JOIN (
select DepartmentID, AVG(Salary) as average_salary
from Employee 
GROUP BY DepartmentID) xx  ON xx.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID;
```

Comment: Rahul thank you!!! Yes this is the answer I was looking for. Eric thank you too :)